# XSL FO inline without space between

Tags: xslt, pdf-generation, xsl-fo

I am trying to make pdf with inline blocs that are next to each other. For a reason i can not understand for the moment it seems to put spaces in between the outputs if there was nothing, for example (i selected the text to better show): 
`<fo:inline>I</fo:inline><fo:inline>I</fo:inline>` results in : 
[example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEJV6.png)
the strange thing is that with text between the two those spaces disapear:
`<fo:inline>I</fo:inline>I<fo:inline>I</fo:inline>`
[example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piE4e.png)

At the end i would like to do pdf from an udeterminated number of blox with xslt transformation, to be able to have results like this : 
[strangely formated output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3kv9.png)
and having space in the middle of words would not do it.

EDIT: for more precision i generate these elements by :

```
<xsl:for-each select="./*"><fo:inline><xsl:value-of select="."/></fo:inline></xsl:for-each>
```

or

```
<xsl:for-each select="./*"><fo:inline><xsl:value-of select="."/></fo:inline>I</xsl:for-each>
```

with nodes containing "I"s. but i got the same results by trying with manual generation.
tried: 
with space between nodes, all together (no space between nodes), and commentaries.

Comment: From the layout of the text of your question, it is not clear if there is a space between the two first instances of `<fo:inline>I</fo:inline>`, because in that case, it is clear that a space is appearing between both "I".

Comment: Thank you for the the suggestion, i tried without spaces in between. (added precision to the original question)

Comment: `select="./*"` (which is equivalent to `select="*"`) will select only element nodes (see, e.g., https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#node-tests). Every axis has a 'principal node type' that matches '*', and for the child axis, it's element nodes.

Comment: Do you have `<xsl:output indent="yes" />` in your stylesheet? (See https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-output)  If so, the XSLT processor could be adding the extra spaces.  Are the spaces in the XSL-FO when you run just the XSLT transform and write the XSL-FO to a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding a work around (i am not sure how much it is a good way to do it tough so i prefer to post it as "an answer instead of "the answer" )
if i put the tag:

```
<fo:block font-size="0px">
</fo:block>
```

around my inline tags, and then add a real size to my tags, i got the results i wanted.
On a side not even the supplementary I characters diaper and can not be selected anymore. I guess the process of XSL-FO needs to be seen more as a "printing" then a text editing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to introduce an empty comment like this:

```
<fo:inline>I</fo:inline><!--
--><fo:inline>I</fo:inline>
```

Comment: Thank you for the the suggestion, i tried with comments. (added precision to the original question)

Comment: @T.S. Normally, on StackExchange, you should give the code you are using, a sample of input, the result it gives and the result you were expecting. Suddenly, by editing your question and adding one of these elements, I see the problem could come from the selection: `<xsl:for-each select="./*">`. Since I don't see the input file, I can't see if the wildcard `*` is not selecting some unwanted white space.

Comment: indeed it needs some "used-to" to be able to formulate these questions as precisely as needed. 
I will try to join the fo file if i can find it. For the moment our process goes as a stream from database => intermediate java objects => xml from it => xslt to tranform => xsl fo => pdf.
The disadvantage of working "in intervention" mode